# Is there a restricted combination on Item Types in Virtual Folders?

Tags: 2013, search

So if I have two virtual folders, one listing localized [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwPbM.jpg) keywords (and categories) and the other listing localized [2] components I'd figured I could combine the two as below:

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <GeneralParameters>
        <SearchQuery></SearchQuery>
        <SearchIn xlink:href="tcm:0-[pubID]-1" Recursive="true"></SearchIn>
    </GeneralParameters>
    <AdvancedParameters>
        <ItemTypes>
            <ItemType>16</ItemType>
            <ItemType>512</ItemType>
            <ItemType>1024</ItemType>
        </ItemTypes>
        <BluePrinting StatusType="Localized">
            <Publication xlink:href=""></Publication>
        </BluePrinting>
    </AdvancedParameters>
</SearchFolder>
```

Unfortuantely the above only lists the Categories and Keywords and ignores components.

When I select the edit the details again I can see that all three are selected... looks like a defect to me but wanted to check if I've missed something in the setup / documentation here.

[image: Item Types confirmed as active]

### Update (added detail)

**1** Item types used for Categories and Keywords

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder">
<GeneralParameters>
    <SearchQuery></SearchQuery>
    <SearchIn xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:0-xxx-1" Recursive="true"></SearchIn>
</GeneralParameters>
<AdvancedParameters>
    <ItemTypes>
        <ItemType>1024</ItemType>
    </ItemTypes>
    <BluePrinting StatusType="Localized">
        <Publication xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href=""></Publication>
    </BluePrinting>
</AdvancedParameters>
```

**2** Item types used for Components

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<GeneralParameters>
    <SearchQuery></SearchQuery>
    <SearchIn xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:xxx-x-2" Recursive="true" xlink:title="Building Blocks"></SearchIn>
</GeneralParameters>
<AdvancedParameters>
    <BluePrinting StatusType="Localized">
        <Publication xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href=""></Publication>
    </BluePrinting>
</AdvancedParameters>
```

**3** Item types used for Components *and* Keywords

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder">
<GeneralParameters>
    <SearchQuery></SearchQuery>
    <SearchIn xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:0-xxx-1" Recursive="true"></SearchIn>
</GeneralParameters>
<AdvancedParameters>
    <ItemTypes>
        <ItemType>1024</ItemType>
        <ItemType>512</ItemType>
        <ItemType>16</ItemType>
    </ItemTypes>
    <BluePrinting StatusType="Localized">
        <Publication xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href=""></Publication>
    </BluePrinting>
</AdvancedParameters>
```

Comment: Just tried it locally on my system, seems like it is working. Can you share the two separate virtual folder configurations, which returns the data (one for localized keywords and categories and the other for localized components).

Comment: Hey thanks for this Likhan - I'll double check on another system I have access to also and will post the virtual folder 'full' properties here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no restrictions that I know of. I've just tried it on my own system and it worked fine.

You can always create the virtual folder by first doing a Search within the CME and then saving it as a Search Folder. That way, you know that there aren't any issues in the XML.